# The Lady or the Tiger , Logical Labyrinth by Smullyan

Tags: logic, puzzle

I won’t repeat the question (#12 - the fourth day) but for the last of the lady or tiger set in chapter 2 I believe either the solution is problematic or how parts of the puzzle is worded are problematic.

I believe this is mainly due to that from sign 3 and sign 5 he uses the word “either” as in either A or B  when it’s pretty clear from the solution he means Logical OR, but where I and others would be only be able to understand it as Logical XOR.  If you assume logical XOR the Lady can be in either room 1 or room 7.

[See these two Solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgbVh.jpg) where (b) is the solution given and (a) is also valid given “either” means XOR.

If the above reasoning is correct then it would be better if the puzzle just dropped the word “either.”

Answer (score 1):

While ‘either’ is indeed often used to express an exclusive or, this is not a hard rule. Consider some who says:

‘I want to be either rich or happy’

Do you think this person will mind if they turn out to be rich *and* happy? No, of course not.

So, despite the use of ‘either’, the speaker is expressing an inclusive or, rather than an exclusive.

Comment: I agree. But, from the problem text alone, is it at all clear which is meant? In a complicated problem like this, for me that subtle ambiguity went unrecognized until I looked at the solution.

Comment: And there I agree with you! No, it is not clear. I've done Smullyan's puzzles, and that always bothered me as well. But I now know that he means the logical (inclusive) or (hey, they're logic puzzles, after all!), and that if he wants an exclusive or, he'll explicitly use something like: 'one of these two statements are true'. But yeah, none of that is clear when you run into one of these puzzles for the first time. In fact, the first time I did one of these, I reasoned he must have meany an inclusive or because if interpreted as exclusive, there was no unique solution :P